# Why does calling an Action, that is null, throw NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, action, nullreferenceexception

Why do I have to check if an `Action` is not `null` to avoid getting a `NullReferenceException`? Isn't it logical if there is no action, then it's okay to just do nothing and proceed? I don't understand why it has to throw an exception. `Action` is a class, why doesn't it handle this itself?

Comment: Them's the rules, and they keep you safe. Why don't all errors just get swallowed? Then all programs would "work"!

Comment: I'm confused that you've changed the accepted answer, despite the one which is now accepted not answering the actual question you asked, about *why* you're getting an exception.

Comment: Jon, come on, you're one of the smartest people on the site :) The actual underlying problem I had was finding a way to invoke the action without getting an exception if it was unset. The C# 6.0 `?.` thing works perfectly and is much more concise. This is why it's my personal answer of choice, and the rest of the users can vote on what they think is best.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet, specially because he's one of the smartest people on the site. You asked `why`, and the chosen answer doesn't present the `why`, while Jon's answer present both the `why` and `how` that you were looking for.

Comment: @mFeinstein Jon might be smart, but the reason I asked was not related to that :p

Comment: You never mentioned your reasons in your question, and as smart as we all are we are still not mind readers... Yes, we could have assumed your reasons behind it, but you know the saying "when you ASSUME you make an ASS out of U and ME"... I think the answer has to match the question, if you are looking for something else, you should ask it accordingly... But that's just my 2 cents on this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since C# 6.0 you can:

```
myAction?.Invoke();
```

No extension methods needed.

Comment: It's possible to use this on C# 4.0 ?

Comment: Are you asking for C# language version or .NET Framework version? Just wanted to make sure, because they are versioned separately.

Comment: Is for Unity game engine, and they use .Net Framework version 3.5

Comment: The null conditional operator does not depend on the framework version itself, but rather on the compiler, which must support that feature. If you use Visual Studio 2015 or later you can still target .net 3.5 and use the operator at the same time.

Answer (score 18):

You're trying to invoke an instance method (`Invoke`) on an object. Doing that *always* fails with a `NullReferenceException` if you're using a `null` reference<sup>1</sup>. For example:

```
 object x = null;
 string y = x.ToString();
```

Should `object.ToString()` handle that too?

Basically, this is consistent with the way the rest of the type system works. The C# language *could* have been designed in a different way - potentially only for the "shorthand" of `action()` meaning `action.Invoke()` - but it wasn't, and it's not going to change now.

It's easy enough to add your own extension method to `Action` if you want to:

```
public static class ActionExtensions
{
    public static void NullSafeInvoke(this Action action)
    {
        if (action != null)
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Or [use the C# 6 *null-conditional operator*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/) to only invoke the delegate when the reference is non-null:

```
myAction?.Invoke();
```

(This works for any delegate type, not just actions - for `EventHandler` for example, you'd use something like `handler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs())`. The `EventArgs()` constructor won't even be called if `handler` is null.)

---

<sup>1</sup> At least using C#. There are ways of invoking instance methods non-virtually "on" null references in IL, but it's far from the normal.

Comment: I think I'll use the extension.

Comment: In VB I'm getting *'NullSafeInvoke' is not a member of 'System.Action'*. All of my other dozens of extension methods right beside it work without complaint. Is there something special we have to do to wire up an `Action` extension method?

Comment: Never mind, it was a build/reference issue. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 8):

`Action` is a delegate, not a class. When you invoke an action, like so:

```
myAction();
```

What really is happening here is this:

```
myAction.Invoke();
```

If `myAction` is `null` you are calling `Invoke` on a `null` instance, which is what naturally raises a `NullReferenceException`.